# Realm Studioで作成したRealmファイルを自作アプリで使用したい

Tags: swift, realm, swiftui

Realmについて質問です。
SwiftUIを使ってアプリを開発中なのですが、Realm Studioで作成したRealmファイルをアプリ内で使う場合にはどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか。

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: URL("filetopath")!, readOnly: true)
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

ここまでは行ったのですが、

```
let data = realm.objects(Hoge.self)
print(data)
```

しても中身が表示されません。

Realmもほぼ触ったことがなく、Swiftに関しても初心者なので教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。

プロジェクトフォルダの中に Realm ファイルを入れ、以下のコードできました。

```
let realm = try! Realm(fileURL: URL(string: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "realm")!)!)
```